# ARM USART program for STM32f107

Tags: embedded, arm, usart

I have configured the usart but i am getting error  in the following line of code and i am using eclipse OCD for the compiling so please suggest the proper way to configure the clock.

```
void RCC_Configuration(void)
{
    /* error status */
    ErrorStatus HSEStartUpStatus;

    RCC_DeInit();

    RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    HSEStartUpStatus = RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp();

    if (HSEStartUpStatus == SUCCESS) {
        FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(FLASH_PrefetchBuffer_Enable);
        FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);

        RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1); 
        RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div1); 
        RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);

        RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSE_Div1, RCC_PLLMul_9);
        RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
        while (RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY) == RESET);

        RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);
        while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08);
    }

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);
}
```

so please suggest the answer 
and thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Which is the line where you get the error (your posting contains more than one line)?

Comment: You may be guilty of believing [The Guru Myth](http://www.toomuchcode.org/2008/11/guru-myth.html).

Comment: FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(FLASH_PrefetchBuffer_Enable);

Comment: RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSE_Div1, RCC_PLLMul_9);
        RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
        while (RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY) == RESET);            this are the line where i am getting error but i dont know it is the problem of compiler or another thing.                                 also i have included all the header file related to the project and the interconnection in my programming

Comment: @sHamiR: You should clarify your question by editing the question, not by adding a comment,  as you can see comments do not have the formatting features of a post, and cannot be voted on in the same way - fix the question to prevent down votes on it.  Further more you have not answered the question: "What is the error..."; if the compiler, debugger or runtime is presenting a diagnostic message do you not think that it is perhaps germane to diagnosis!?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is not directly related to the USART, rather it is the system PLL configuration for the entire chip.

Quite apart from what this particular issue might be, you might do better to use the standard STM32F1xx CMSIS start-up code in system_stm32f10x.c, which sets the PLL in any case. startup_stm32f10x_cl.s (the start-up code for STM32F1xx Conectivity Line devices).  You only need to modify system_stm32f10x.c to match your board's crystal frequency, and it will set the clock and other necessary initialisation before main() is called.

The CMSIS can be obtained from STM's site, but is I believe included in the standard peripheral library which you appear to be using in any case.